# Cocoa App (swift) - how to enter full screen automatically on app startup

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift, fullscreen

Basically I would like to know how to make my app start out in full screen mode.

I've tried to use toggleFullscreen, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.
Others have suggested using NSApplication.sharedapplication().setPresentationOptions(--options--), but it seems to have been removed at some point.

Hope someone can help, and if so, thanks in advance for your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the `NSWindow`'s collection behavior to `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary`?

Comment: This is not making it full screen automatically